# Regex to specify exactly one occurrence of the matched content

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build some regex in order to match div classes in an html page. Have a look at this example:

```
<div class="ba bb bc bd be">

<div class="ba bb">
```

What i need is a RegEX to get only the second class (ba bb), so five characters at all including the middle space. I tried

> [a-z ]{4}

But it doesn't work. I don't know how to do that.

EDIT 1: I use the site https://regexr.com/ in order to test against the text i provided.

With the regex

> [a-z ]{2} [a-z ]{2}

and also with

> [a-z]{2}\s[a-z]{2}

I get <d**iv cl**ass="**ba bb** **bc bd** be">

But i only need a single match for the second one, so this regex matches more than i need.

With the regex

> '"([a-z]{2}) \1"'

it does not match anything. I need to specify that i can't use the double quotes character because i need to use this regex inside BeautifulSoup, so that types of characters are removed from source.

Comment: whats about: [a-z ]{2} [a-z ]{2}

Comment: It doesn't work as i expect

Answer (score 0):

This regex should help you:

```
[a-z]{2}\s[a-z]{2} #4 alphabets in total, 2 on the left, 2 on the right, separated by a space
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first define the double-letter groups and then tell re how many such groups are there. Perhaps this will help:

```
'\"([a-z]{2}) \1\"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, with a **quote delimiter**:

```
"[a-z ]{2} [a-z ]{2}"
```

Comment: @docdev try this one, with quote delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(?<=class=\")[a-z ]{5}(?=\")
```

this match value inside class attribute just if the size of value exactly 5 (check this link https://regex101.com/r/vRS42u/1)

but if you exactly need to match 2 alphabets then 1 space and again 2 alphabets maybe this pattern can help you

```
(?<=class=\")[a-z]{2} [a-z]{2}(?=\")
```